# macro equivalent (C/C++)?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Given this macro:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(ret, f, args) \
    typedef ret (*some_func_##f) args; \
    static some_func_##f my_func_##f = NULL;
```

Please let me know the equivalent for:

```
SOME_MACRO(void,  myFunctionName, (int a));
```

Thanks.

Comment: You mean, without using the preprocessor, right?

Comment: @bitmask, yes. I want to know what SOME_MACRO(void,  myFunctionName, (int a)); gets translated to? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-E` flag of gcc to see how the macro is expanded:

```
typedef void (*some_func_myFunctionName) (int a); static some_func_myFunctionName my_func_myFunctionName = ((void *)0);;
```

Comment: You can use the equivalent `/EP` switch in MSVC.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void (*my_func_myFunctionName) (int a) = NULL;
```

It declares a variable `my_func_myFunctionName` as a function pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns nothing (`void`). It initialises the variable to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #define SOME_MACRO(ret, f, args) \
    typedef ret (*some_func_##f) args; \
    static some_func_##f my_func_##f = NULL;
```

SOME_MACRO(void,  myFunctionName, (int a));

will translate to

```
typedef void (*some_func_myFunctionName) (int a); //## concats myFunctionName to some_func_, ret becomes void
static some_func_myFunctionName my_func_myFunctionName = NULL;
```

> ```
>  ##f concats myFunctionName to some_func_,
>  ret becomes void
>  args is (int a)
> ```